# Python sleep without blocking other processes

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am running a python script every hour and I've been using `time.sleep(3600)` inside of a while loop. It seems to work as needed but I am worried about it blocking new tasks. My research of this seems to be that it only blocks the current thread but I want to be 100% sure. While the hourly job shouldn't take more than 15min, if it does or if it hangs, I don't want it to block the next one that starts. This is how I've done it:

```
import threading
import time


def long_hourly_job():
    # do some long task
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        thr = threading.Thread(target=long_hourly_job)
        thr.start()
        time.sleep(3600)
```

Is this sufficient?

Also, the reason i am using `time.sleep` for this hourly job rather than a cron job is I want to do everything in code to make dockerization cleaner.

Comment: `time.sleep` blocks the current thread only.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks Tim. That's what I thought, so my current implementation should be fine then right?

Comment: @guy yes it should start `long_hourly_job` every 3600 seconds. But if your `long_hourly_job` takes more than 1 hour to run, there could be overlaps.

Comment: @niranjan94 overlaps are fine as long as nothing is blocked, though you make a good point about maybe killing anything not done within the hour

Comment: May I also suggest looking into apscheduler if you want to have crontab-like jobs be run within a container. I use it for flask-app ML retraining and it's very effective. https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/userguide.html

Comment: @Sam thanks I'll take a look at it though I'd rather have the least amount of dependencies possible for this specific use case.

Comment: Don't forget to `join` the thread at some point.

Comment: @azelcer Not sure what you mean, I have never heard of that concept before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code will work (ie: `sleep` does only block the calling thread), but you should be careful of some issues. Some of them have been already stated in the comments, like the possibility of time overlaps between threads. The main issue is that your code is slowly leaking resources. After creating a thread, the OS keeps some data structures even after the thread has finished running. This is necessary, for example to keep the thread's exit status until the thread's creator requires it. The function to clear these structures (conceptually equivalent to closing a file) is called `join`. A thread that has finished running and is not `join`ed is termed a 'zombie thread'. The amount of memory required by these structures is very small, and your program should run for centuries for any reasonable amount of available RAM. Nevertheless, it is a good practice to join all the threads you create. A simple approach (if you know that 3600 s is more than enough time for the thread to finish) would be:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        thr = threading.Thread(target=long_hourly_job)
        thr.start()
        thr.join(3600)  # wait at most 3600 s for the thread to finish
        if thr.isAlive(): # join does not return useful information
            print("Ooops: the last job did not finish on time")
```

A better approach if you think that it is possible that sometimes 3600 s is not enough time for the thread to finish:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    previous = []
    while True:
        thr = threading.Thread(target=long_hourly_job)
        thr.start()
        previous.append(thr)
        time.sleep(3600)
        for i in reversed(range(len(previous))):
            t = previous[i]
            t.join(0)
            if t.isAlive():
                print("Ooops: thread still running")
            else:
                print("Thread finished")
                previous.remove(t)
```

I know that the `print` statement makes no sense: use `logging` instead.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I was just thinking about this issue last week. I've been afraid of the original thread never really dying and just consuming memory for ever and ever. This seems to resolve that.

Comment: @guy If the original thread never ends (ie: keeps running in an infinite loop or something like that), there is not much you can do, or at last I don't know a way to kill a thread. If you want to kill a job that did not finish on time, you better use `multiprocessing`, but it has some issues of its own.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little late. I tested the code from other answers but my main process got stuck (perhaps I'm doing something wrong?). I then tried a different approach. It's based on threading Timer class, but  trying to emulate the QtCore.QTimer() behavior and features:

```
import threading
import time
import traceback
    
    
class Timer:

    SNOOZE = 0
    ONEOFF = 1

    def __init__(self, timerType=SNOOZE):

        self._timerType = timerType
        self._keep = threading.Event()
        self._timerSnooze = None
        self._timerOneoff = None

    class _SnoozeTimer(threading.Timer):
        # This uses threading.Timer class, but consumes more CPU?!?!?!

        def __init__(self, event, msec, callback, *args):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)

            self.stopped = event
            self.msec = msec
            self.callback = callback
            self.args = args

        def run(self):
            while not self.stopped.wait(self.msec):
                self.callback(*self.args)

    def start(self, msec: int, callback, *args, start_now=False) -> bool:

        started = False
        if msec > 0:
            if self._timerType == self.SNOOZE:
                if self._timerSnooze is None:
                    self._timerSnooze = self._SnoozeTimer(self._keep, msec / 1000, callback, *args)
                    self._timerSnooze.start()
                    if start_now:
                        callback(*args)
                    started = True
            else:
                if self._timerOneoff is None:
                    self._timerOneoff = threading.Timer(msec / 1000, callback, *args)
                    self._timerOneoff.start()
                    started = True
        return started

    def stop(self):
        if self._timerType == self.SNOOZE:
            self._keep.set()
            self._timerSnooze.join()
        else:
            self._timerOneoff.cancel()
            self._timerOneoff.join()

    def is_alive(self):
        if self._timerType == self.SNOOZE:
            isAlive = self._timerSnooze is not None and self._timerSnooze.is_alive() and not self._keep.is_set()
        else:
            isAlive = self._timerOneoff is not None and self._timerOneoff.is_alive()
        return isAlive
    isAlive = is_alive


KEEP = True
    
def callback():
    global KEEP
    KEEP = False
    print("ENDED", time.strftime("%M:%S"))
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    count = 0
    t = Timer(timerType=Timer.ONEOFF)
    t.start(5000, callback)
    print("START", time.strftime("%M:%S"))
    while KEEP:
        if count % 10000000 == 0:
            print("STILL RUNNING")
        count += 1
```

Notice the while loop runs in a separate thread, and uses a callback function to invoke when the time is over (in your case, this callback function would be used to check if the long running process has finished).